# Passing parameters to a Twilio via CallResource.CreateAsync to programmatically add a bot to a conference call

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying to create a conference call with a Moderator and several participants one of which is a bot.
The bot is controlled by the Moderator via a back channel so it can Say things etc to the conference call.

I setup the conference call when the Moderator calls in from a web client and then dial in the other participants and the bot using `CallResource.CreateAsync` with a callback url so I know which conference to add them to.
The bot needs to get a parameter so it knows which moderator to listen to for instructions.
However, I can't seem to pass any parameters to the bot (which is currently being triggered via another TwiML app) from the C# API using `CallResource.CreateAsync`.

Adding a participant to the call (callbackUrl adds the connected call to the conference) - this works fine:

```
var to = new PhoneNumber(callData.PhoneNumber);
var from = new PhoneNumber(_twilioSettings.PhoneNumber);
var callbackUrl = GetConnectConferenceUrl(callData.CallToken);
var url = new Uri(callbackUrl);
var participantCallResource = await CallResource.CreateAsync(to, from, url: url);
```

Adding the bot to call (Phone number is setup in Twilio as a TwiML app with a webhook back to my server) - how do I pass parameters to the TwiML app?

```
var toBot = new PhoneNumber(botNumber);
var fromBot = new PhoneNumber(_twilioSettings.PhoneNumber);
var botCallbackUrl = GetConnectConferenceUrl(callData.CallToken, isBot: true);
var botUrl = new Uri(botCallbackUrl);
var botCallResource = await CallResource.CreateAsync(toBot, fromBot, url: botUrl)
```

How do I pass parameters to a TwiML bin or Webhook or phonenumber from C#?

Do I need to add the bot in to the call a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed either on the `To` or on the `Url` per https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications

I believe your use case would put it on the `Url`. Assuming you have a `moderatorId`:

```
var botCallbackUrl = GetConnectConferenceUrl(callData.CallToken, isBot: true, moderatorId);
var botUrl = new Uri(botCallbackUrl);
```

where `GetConnectConferenceUrl` adds the parameter you need.

I've used it on the `To` line for a Client endpoint, so that looked like

```
var toBot = $"{new PhoneNumber(botNumber)}?moderatorId={moderatorId}";
```